# To chronologically sort rows in group of 4 in r dataframe

Tags: r

i have a data frame with first column as id and second column as date . other 3 columns contains some other random values.

size of data frame = 5 columns and 160000 rows.

I want to sort the first 4 records based on chronological order of date against those records in second column.
oldest record among 4 should come first and latest record should come last.
After this i have to go on sorting next all rows in group of 4.

```
ID  Date        A   B   C   
X   10/27/2011  12  47  78
Y   09/28/2015  27  14  41
Z   01/14/2013  24  25  45
W   04/21/2005  14  74  21
-
-
-
-
upto 160000 rows



 output

    ID  Date        A   B   C
    W   04/21/2005  14  74  21
    X   10/27/2011  12  47  78
    Z   01/14/2013  24  25  45
    Y   09/28/2015  27  14  41

-
-
-
upto 160000 rows
```

any way to do this?

I am using this as of now but unable to split this into groups for 4 rows

```
d[order(as.Date(d$df, format="%d/%m/%Y")),]
```

the data type of column is integer. and i am trying to read it as date.

Thanks

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Is your date column of type Date/POSIXct etc or character ? @simone is right... we need a reproducible example

Comment: Thanks I have added an example in question.

Comment: Mmh... your format `"%d/%m/%Y"` is not consistent with your example data that seem more like `"%m/%d/%Y"`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the integer division `%/%` to give a "virtual" index to each group of four :

```
# recreate a random DF
set.seed(123)
DF <- 
data.frame(ID=paste0('ID',1:10),
           Date=c("21/06/2017", "23/06/2017", "10/06/2017", "18/06/2017", "27/06/2017", 
                  "01/06/2017", "13/06/2017", "07/06/2017", "24/06/2017", "05/06/2017"),
           A=rnorm(10,4,100))

# define virtual indexes
groupsOf4 <- (1:nrow(DF)-1) %/% 4
# order by groupsOf4 and then by Date
sortedDF <- DF[order(groupsOf4, as.Date(DF$Date, format="%d/%m/%Y")),]
```

Result :

```
> DF
     ID       Date          A
1   ID1 21/06/2017  -52.04756
2   ID2 23/06/2017  -19.01775
3   ID3 10/06/2017  159.87083
4   ID4 18/06/2017   11.05084
5   ID5 27/06/2017   16.92877
6   ID6 01/06/2017  175.50650
7   ID7 13/06/2017   50.09162
8   ID8 07/06/2017 -122.50612
9   ID9 24/06/2017  -64.68529
10 ID10 05/06/2017  -40.56620

> sortedDF
     ID       Date          A
3   ID3 10/06/2017  159.87083
4   ID4 18/06/2017   11.05084
1   ID1 21/06/2017  -52.04756
2   ID2 23/06/2017  -19.01775
6   ID6 01/06/2017  175.50650
8   ID8 07/06/2017 -122.50612
7   ID7 13/06/2017   50.09162
5   ID5 27/06/2017   16.92877
10 ID10 05/06/2017  -40.56620
9   ID9 24/06/2017  -64.68529
```

Comment: Thanks digEmAll for the help

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an index column eg with a repeated value every four rows, you can then use this to sort in groups.

I've provided an example here, you can modify this with your date column, but it's the same idea.

```
d <- data.frame(ID = 1:16, df = as.integer(runif(16, 0,30)))

# add an index
d$by <- rep(1:(nrow(d)/4), each = 4)
d

# sort by the index
sort.ind <- by(d, d$by, function(x) x[order(x$df, decreasing = T),])

# bind the sorted data frames together
d.sort <- do.call(rbind, sort.ind)

d.sort
```